# How to add gravity to picking objects in Unity

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

I have created a simple log file with Javascript that with this script ,the first person character is be able to pick up objects and move them to another place. But the problem is sometimes the objects are placed in the air! For example in this picture ,you can see the object which is a cylinder is positioned above the ground...

[image]

So how to adjust settings to objects that they MUST be placed ON the ground ? 
I mean if a user picked up an object and even if he put the object up in the sky ,the object should fall down and place on the ground due to gravity stuff.

Here's the JS code that I've added:

```
    //Jimmy Vegas Unity Tutorial
//This script will allow you to pick up and move objects


var target : Transform;


function Update () {

}

function OnMouseDown() {

    this.transform.position = target.position;
    this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("FPSController").transform;
    this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("FirstPersonCharacter").transform;

}


function OnMouseUp() {

    this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("FPSController").transform;
    this.transform.parent = null;

}
```

Comment: Not good to delete your question when good answer is provided. It's a bad way to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your `GameObjects` to be affected by gravity you can attach a `Rigidbody` and turn on gravity.

Another remark: You have unnecessary code in the Snippet you provided. In `OnMouseDown` the second assignment of `this.transform.parent` does override the first one, so you can leave the first one out. The same applies to `OnMouseUp`.